# How to add ActionRow to a message in jda

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want to add an `ActionRow` to a message

i tried

```java
ActionRow row1 = ActionRow.of(Button.danger("top_btn" , "top button"))
ActionRow row2 = ActionRow.of(Button.danger("buttom_btn" , "button button"))

event.getMessage().reply("this is buttons")
.setActionRow(row1 ,row2)
```

And it returned error

I also tried `.setACtionRows` instead of `setActionRow` but is was undefined .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "setComponents" or "addComponents" instead of setActionRow.

https://jda.wiki/using-jda/interactions/#component-interactions